# Is there a simple text-editor, opening up a webserver from the command-line?

Tags: text-editor, command-line, web-server, unix

I have a set-up with some files on a Unix-system.  And I want to edit them in real-time from remote via a webbrowser-app. I have commandline access on this system. Now I am searching for a tool making it possible to open up an WYSIWG-plain-text-editor with a webserver.

My dream is finding a programm with a usage like this:
`$ texteditor show <filename>`
Then the file is editable, if I open the browser on the webservers port.

Using a node.js app for this would also be possible for my setup. Maybe there is a simple module for that, encapsulating the websocket and the other stuff.

Comment: Can't you use Putty to Telnet in and edit them on the remote system?

Comment: Unfortunately not, beacuse it has to be usable form the Browser...

Comment: Does it matter which browser?

Comment: No ist does not mater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Shellinabox](https://code.google.com/archive/p/shellinabox/) is web server that can export arbitrary command line tools to a web based terminal emulator.

By default it will enable a normal SSH connection.
You could create a user/group with limited permission to only edit the files you want.

[Here](https://www.unixmen.com/shellinabox-a-web-based-ajax-terminal-emulator/) is an example configuration.

Comment: Great, pretty cool tool. If I combine it with `nano` it's a q&d workaround for my problem.For a good usable sulotion, I try to build in the long term sth with [atom in orbit](https://github.com/facebook-atom/atom-in-orbit).

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse Che](https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/) provides a web based IDE. It has many advanced features like multiples language support, environments, etc.

You can [use for a single user](https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/setup/getting-started/index.html)  with docker.

But, as your scenario seems to be pretty simple, it feels like overkill.

Comment: Thanks for you recommendation, I tried it. But as you said my scenario is pretty simple, and Eclipse is a bit featurefull. Maybe I am able to mody Eclipse Che  in a way, that makes it compatible. with my scenario.